# Linux (Centos) soft raid1 - motherboard died

Tags: linux, centos, raid

I use centos 6.3 and soft raid1 (via mdraid) + LVM. The problem is that MB died and I have several questions.

1. I have two hard drives. Is it important what drive how connect to MB. I mean slave/master and etc. Besides I don't remember how they were connected before.
2. Should I just replace MB and swith server on? I mean will OS auto determine MB change?
3. Should I do something else not to loose data?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array isn't positively ancient (kernel 2.2 vintage), each volume has a MD header containing information about how the array is constructed.  Among other things, the header contains the UUID of the array the volume belongs to and the volume's position within that array.  Since this information is available, MD RAID doesn't care how the drives are connected.  You could probably reassemble the array even if you put one of the drives in a USB enclosure and served the other up over the network as an `nbd` device -- though I wouldn't recommend such a crazy setup.

Note, however, that if your array is using version 0.90 metadata rather than version 1.0 or newer, some parts of the header are CPU-specific.  It's difficult to move such an array from, for example, x86 to PowerPC, and moving from x86 to x86-64 may also have problems.

Answer (score 0):

you should make sure you note which is the ide master and slave

If its the same motherboard you'll be ok to just swap it out. It happens every now and then when a server motherboard will die and a vendor will just swap it out and everything comes up just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Unfortunatety it's impossible now to determine what was master and what was slave. Can I do something with it? And motherboard is now different.

Comment: plug in the server with a single drive and the system should find a degrated raid.. then shutdown and format the other in rescue mode then reboot with it and it should repair